# How can I access the return value of all my promises?

Tags: jquery, ajax

[This article](http://www.tentonaxe.com/index.cfm/2011/9/22/Using-jQuerywhen-with-a-dynamic-number-of-objects) shows how to `wait` for a dynamic number of ajax requests to finish.  He does the following:

```
var deferredArr = $.map($(".dynaload"), function(el, i) { 
    return $.ajax({ 
        url: $(el).data("loadUrl"), 
        success: function(html) { 
            $(el).html(html); 
        } 
    }); 
}); 
$.when.apply(this, deferredArr).then(function() { 
    alert("All Done Loading!"); 
});
```

The problem is that the function that resolves the deferreds takes as many parameters as there are deferreds. So, if I do this:

```
$.when.apply(this, deferredArr).then(function(data) { 
    alert("All Done Loading!"); 
});
```

Then `data` is just the result of the first promise. How can I get all the results without resorting to appending the results in an array?

Comment: You can use `.done()` instead of `.then()` and do `.done(function(data1, data2, data3) {...});`

Comment: But I don't know how many `data` arguments I have. I may have 2, I may have 5, I may have none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions with unknown number of arguments can use the special `arguments` array:

```
$.when.apply(this, deferredArr).then(function() { 
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log("Promise "+i+" returned: "+arguments[i]);
    }
    alert("All Done Loading!"); 
});
```

See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) for documentation and more examples of arguments usage.

Comment: Where/How did you find this? :)

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS Added link to documentation

Comment: So this is a JS feature, not a jQuery feature. Awesome!

Comment: Deferreds are a feature of jQuery (and other libs). `.apply()` and `arguments` are plain javascript. `.apply()` and its close friend `.call()` are well worth learning.